# How to get Preview image from Opencamera camera1 api in android(java) application

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, camera-api, cameraapi2

We have android camera based application ,in that we have used opencamera camera2 api's preview image .Recently we started using Moto g62 5g android phone, in this phone we are not getting proper image for camera2 api. So we thought to use open camera camera1 api, But in open camera camera1 api preview image is not available .So how can i get preview image from open camera camera1 api in android java

Comment: What is wrong with the camera2 API image? It's very likely you'll get the same image via camera1, since fundamentally the data comes from the same camera HAL.

Comment: @EddyTalvala Earlier we have used Vivo 1917 Android phone, in that camera2 api's preview images are good in clarity. But now we started using Moto g62 5g android phone in that preview images are not  good in clarity. We have checked the camera properties also..  I have come across the below blog in which they mentioned the issue related Moto device below    https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G5-Moto-G5-Plus/Camera-2-api-manual-mode/td-p/3657797